# Trying to show info from database into terminal

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm trying to display a list of the names of people in the database from the terminal, but not sure about how I would go about this. Right now I'm using a prepared statement

```
public static void showNames() throws SQLException {
        Statement stmt=null;
        Connection conn=null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String selectTable="SELECT * FROM userInfo;";
        stmt.execute(selectTable);
    }
```

Comment: ...and what is your question, or what is wrong the above code?

Comment: Use [executeQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) - it will return a `ResultSet` from which you can obtain the data

Comment: Capture the result Set returned by stmt.execute, iterate over result set to capture values in you variables and use system.out.println to print..so far you are on right track

Answer (score 0):

You're close.

Below code is not a complete answer, but hopefully enough to get you moving in the direction of obtaining a complete answer. The below code is basically the code you posted with some modifications.

```
public static void showNames() throws SQLException {
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    String selectTable="SELECT * FROM userInfo;";
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectTable);
        while (rs.next()) {
            Object obj = rs.getObject("name of column in database table USERINFO");
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

You didn't post the structure of database table USERINFO, so replace *name of column in database table* with the actual column name.

By the way, there are many examples of how to do this on the Internet, for example [Processing SQL Statements with JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html).